# Aligned_alloc behaviour

Tags: c++

I have read the man of `aliged_alloc` and I should use it like:

```
void* aligned_alloc( std::size_t alignment, std::size_t size );
```

It returns the pointer I want to `alloc` with the `alignment` and the `size`.

In my code I try to use it:

```
int *a = aligned_alloc(1024, 10*sizeof(a));
```

And with

```
std::cout << alignof(a) << std::endl;
```

it gives me 8. But I expect that the results is 1024 because my alignement is 1024.

What don't I understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The alignment of `a` is not the alignment of the memory pointed to by `a`. The value of 8 given by `alignof(a)` is the required alignment for that type, not the largest alignment of the value of `a`.

When you do `alignof(a)`, it's equivalent to doing `alignof(int *)`, which is required to have an alignment of 8 on your compiler/machine.

Answer (score 3):

The `_Alignof` operator (which is what the `alignof` macro expands to) evaluates to the alignment requirement of the **type** of the given operand, not what it points to (if it's a pointer).

It is evaluated at compile time, so if the operand is a pointer there's no way for it to know what it points to, if anything.

Section 6.5.3.4p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states:

> The
>   `_Alignof` operator  yields  the  alignment  requirement  of  its  operand  type. The operand is not evaluated and the result is an
>   integer constant.  When applied to an array type, the result is the
>   alignment requirement of the element type.

Section 8.3.6 of the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) states:

> *1* An `alignof` expression yields the alignment requirement of its operand type. The operand shall be a type-id representing a complete
>   object type, or an array thereof, or a reference to one of those
>   types.
>
> *2* The result is an integral constant of type `std::size_t` .
>
> *3* When `alignof` is applied to a reference type, the result is the alignment of the referenced type. When alignof is applied to an array
>   type, the result is the alignment of the element type.

Answer (score 0):

`alignof` is a static operator. It'll give you the native alignment of an object's type. `alignof(a)` will be native alignment of an `int*` pointer, and `alignof(*a)` will be the native alignment of an `int`.

`aligned_alloc` isn't a compile-time function. It allocates memory at runtime and the alignment of that memory will be the 2 to the count of trailing zeros in the address stored by the pointer (most easily/efficiently countable with the `__builtin_ctz*` builtins provided by gcc/clang).

The snippet

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdalign.h>

int main()
{
    int *a = (int*)aligned_alloc(1023,1);
    printf("%zu %zu\n", alignof(a), alignof(*a));
    printf("ctz=%u\n",__builtin_ctzll((unsigned long long)a));
    printf("%llu\n",1ull<<__builtin_ctzll((unsigned long long)a));
}
```

run on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51606a7d251103a9 appears to usually return pointers aligned to 2^12 or 2^13--which is OK because such overaligned pointers are most definitely also aligned for 2^10 (==1024).

Example output:

```
8 4
ctz=12
4096
```